# Getting "Invalid block type" exception on Magento 1.9.3.7 for custom template inside catalog/product

Tags: magento-1.9, template, custom-block

I am facing a strange issue. I am getting "Invalid block type" exception for a custom block that I have created. I am using the block like this

```
{{block type="example/menu" name="product.menu" template="catalog/product/menulist.phtml"}}
```

But if I use `template="catalog/product/list.phtml"` no exception is thrown. I get invalid block type exception if I use `template="catalog/product/menulist.phtml"`. I have created the `menulist.phtml` file in `app/design/frontend/rwd/verito/template/catalog/product` directory.

Again, this code also works fine without exception.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="product.menu" template="catalog/product/menulist.phtml"}}
```

I have whitelisted `example/menu` by adding in System/Permissions/Blocks. But I couldn't find out the missing link for the mentioned exception. What am I missing? Do I need to add anything else in catalog.xml or some other xml file?

Here is the log

```
2018-11-11T13:57:17+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Abcde_Example_Block_Menu' in /home/lowplex/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/lowplex/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28794): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /home/lowplex/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28736): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('example/menu', Array)
#2 /home/lowplex/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28771): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('example/menu', 'menu')
#3 /home/lowplex/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28538): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('example/menu', 'menu')
#4 /home/lowplex/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28504): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/lowplex/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14265): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#6 /home/lowplex/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(148): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#7 /home/lowplex/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14339): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#8 /home/lowplex/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18833): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#9 /home/lowplex/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18363): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /home/lowplex/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(21319): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /home/lowplex/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /home/lowplex/public_html/index.php(85): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}
```

app/etc/modules/Abcde_All.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Abcde_Example>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Abcde_Example>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Abcde/Example/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Abcde_Example>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Abcde_Example>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <example>
                <class>Abcde_Example_Block</class>
            </example>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Abcde/Example/Block/Menu.php

```
<?php
class Abcde_Example_Block_Menu extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
}
```

app/design/frontend/rwd/verito/template/catalog/product/menulist.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
 */
?>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

Comment: Is there typo in block file name, or you really defined it with .xml extension. It must have .php extension.

Comment: Its .php file. I have updated in the question.

Comment: In app/etc/modules it should be Abcde_Example.xml

Comment: @RohanHapani Thanks. But getting the same issue after renaming the file.

Answer (score 0):

app/code/local/Abcde/Example/**block**/Menu.php -> **block** folder first letter **B** must be capital. So it is like **Block**

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo. It is "Block". Have updated the question.